# Remove first folder in string

Tags: javascript

I have a folder path that always starts with a certain string which I want to remove. Let's say it looks like this:

```
my-bucket/2929023/32822323/file.jpg
```

I want it to look like this:

```
2929023/32822323/file.jpg
```

How would I do that?

Comment: `.split('/').slice(1).join('/')`

Comment: "*always starts with a certain string*" - then you know the length of the thing to be removed statically, and can hardcode `str.slice(10)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple replace method if the string is only present once;

```js
var string = "my-bucket/2929023/32822323/file.jpg";

var revisedString = string.replace('my-bucket/', '');

console.log(revisedString);
```

However, you're also able to use a Regex (regular expression) to remove it as well, something like;

```js
var string = "my-bucket/2929023/32822323/file.jpg";

console.log(string.replace(/^my-bucket\//, ''));
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as`my-bucket/2929023/my-bucket/32822323/file.jpg` would become `/2929023//32822323/file.jpg`, ie. it might remove too much.

Answer (score 5):

Using the functions `substring` and `indexOf` from `String.prototype`.

```js
var str = "my-bucket/2929023/32822323/file.jpg";
console.log(str.substring(str.indexOf('/') + 1))
```

Comment: This is the best answer (aside from Bergi's comments). A regex replace is overkill and the other other answers have problems depending on the rest of the string after the first `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to rip the first one out. No substrings necessary.

```
var myString= "my-bucket/2929023/32822323/file.jpg";

myString = myString.replace(/^.+?[/]/, '');
```