# Replace first part of string in Java

Tags: java, regex, file, path

I have the following String:

```
String myString = "/folder1/folder2/file.txt";
```

How can I replace the first part of the path wi`folder1` with `newFolder`? I've tried the following (posted here: [Remove first folder in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804163/remove-first-folder-in-string)) but it doesn't do anything, the regex may need tweaked?

```
String newString = myString.replaceAll("/^.+ ?[/]/", "newFolder");
// Expect newString = "/newFolder/folder2/file.txt"
```

Related question which uses `Path` to do this, I'd like to stick with `String` for my solution:

[Replace first part of a Java Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213436/replace-first-part-of-a-java-path)

Comment: Try `myString.replaceAll("^/[^/]+/", "/newFolder/");`

Comment: Use `replaceFirst` (LOL). Also the pattern `"^..."` means from the beginning. Useful in multiline (option) replaces.

Comment: `.replaceFirst("^/?[^/]+", "newFolder")`

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution without regex:

```
String string = "/folder1/folder2/file.txt";
String revisedString = string.replace("folder1", "newFolder");
System.out.println(revisedString); // it will print -> /newFolder/folder2/file.txt
```

with regex:

```
String string = "/folder1/folder2/file.txt";
String revisedString  = string.replaceAll("^/[^/]+/", "/newFolder/");
System.out.println(revisedString ); // it will print -> /newFolder/folder2/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not even use Regular Expressions. You can directly do that by using the replace() method present in String class in Java.

```
String myString = "/folder1/folder2/file.txt";
String folder1 = "qualified and valid name";
String newLocation = myString.replace(folder1,newFolderName);
```

This newFolderName is the folder name with which you want to replace the folder1.